# Dock window in VB6

Tags: forms, vb6, window, docking

How to dock form to another form (like VB6's Immediate, Debug forms...)?
I've tried to do it with a MDI Form and a child form, but I couldn't dock child form to MDI parent.
Also I've found some third-party controls but I'd like to do it without them.

Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could check out [Developer Fusion Dockable Window Control](http://www.developerfusion.com/product/332/dockable-window-control/). The screenshots look promising.

From the overview:

> This control (only 44KB!) allows you to add a dockable window to your
>   VB Project.
>
> - Dock top, left, right or bottom
> - 'Tear off' to undock form
> - Autodock by moving form to edge of parent form
> - 'Window memory' (the control remembers the dockable windows last position, which is restored when your application loads again.

Comment: dead `"File with such name does not exist."`. You should provide code here.